# SAPUI5 and screen reader

Tags: sapui5, accessibility, screen-readers

I have some issues with SAPUI5 framework and screen reader.
For example on Android with Voice Assistent and Chrome browser, when you tap a button, the voice assistent always calls - what I guess is coming from the icon - twice.

```
<core:InvisibleText id="ariaSettings" text="{i18n>ariaSettings}"/>
<Button id="btnSettings" icon="sap-icon://action-settings" press=".onSettings" ariaDescribedBy="ariaSettings"/>
```

So it says: "Settings comma Settings..."

Any idea how to avoid this? On iOS with Safari and Voiceover it works.

Also for example with sap.m.GenericTile Control, the screen reader always says when you tap on it at the very beginning "Generic Tile...."

Are there in general ways to hide such things in SAPUI5? I know that there are HTML properties like aria-hidden but in SAPUI5 framework I can't find them. Most items only have ariaDescribedBy or ariaLabelledBy properties and that's it.